# Cannot boot into desktop after crashing

Tags: pi-3, boot, crash

Good day all,

I am new to the Raspberry Pi. I have just purchased a Raspberry pi 3. I downloaded the Raspbian  OS and installed it on a brand new 16GB Kingston microSD card.

First time I was successful booting into desktop, set up into my WIFI network. 
I opened Chromium and opened a youtube page... The screen froze for 10 mins with no response to any keyboard nor mouse. I unplugged the power source.

Upon start up, I could see the booting image, raspberry pi symbol, then the screen went black with a prompt.
I can manage to get it to go to console Ctrl+Alt+F1

please let me know what I can do from here.

Thank you.

Comment: try re-installing raspbian on a different SD card

Comment: What is the LED's telling you? Follow the troubleshooting at https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Comment: What does `journalctl -e` tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- Since, you can manage to get in to the console. Try typing **startx** to boot into GUI.
- PowerOff your Raspberry Pi, remove the SD Card and re-insert it.
- Reinstall Raspbian on new SD Card and try it.